# Redimensional Input Bootstrap no Form Inline

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

Tenho o seguinte form inline, e gostaria de redimensionar o input conforme o desenho:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Segue código:

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-lg-12">
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">Pesquisar</div>
    <div class="panel-body">

      <form class="form-inline ">
        <div class="form-group">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="sel1">Select list:</label>
            <select class="form-control" id="sel1">
              <option>1</option>
              <option>2</option>
              <option>3</option>
              <option>4</option>
            </select>
          </div>
        </div>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="campoPesquisa">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Pesquisar</button>
      </form>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Já tentei colocar dentro de uma row, fora da row. Dúvida de iniciante.

Answer (score 1):

Opa Brother, tranquilo ?

Bem tem inúmeras formas, vou mostrar uma que eu utilizo, que só tu vai usar uma classe própria do Bootstrap!

Que seria Offsetting columns!

É importante que você lembre do conceito de grid que é utilizado no bootstrap, bele ?

No seu código ficaria assim:

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-lg-12">
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">Pesquisar</div>
    <div class="panel-body">

      <form class="form-inline col-lg-offset-7">
        <div class="form-group">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="sel1">Select list:</label>
            <select class="form-control" id="sel1">
              <option>1</option>
              <option>2</option>
              <option>3</option>
              <option>4</option>
            </select>
          </div>
        </div>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="campoPesquisa">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Pesquisar</button>
      </form>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Perceba que dentro da classe do form, eu coloquei a col-lg-offset-7, que seria basicamente um margem left por meio das grid, ou seja, essa coluna pula 7 blocos para o lado direito!

E o mais legal é que mantem a responsividade do projeto!

Como disse, exite inúmeras formas de fazer isso, essa é a que eu gosto de usar!

Edit: No caso de redimensionar o input é simples também: Basta adicionar uma classe no input e mexer na width:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control input-custom"id="campoPesquisa">
```

e no css coloque algo assim:

.input-custom {width:75%;}

E ajuste a porcentagem de acordo com a sua necessidade

Comment: E ai, obrigado pela resposta, porem ele deslocou o conteúdo para a direita. Eu já tinha deslocado ele sem querer, porem queria era redimensionar o intput para maior.

Comment: Perdão se entendi errado, no caso você deseja aumentar o campo do select ?

Comment: Não, o input que gostaria de redimensionar.

Comment: Fiz um edit, na minha postagem comentando sobre a input, da uma olhada e ver se te ajuda brother!

Answer (score 1):

Velho eu consegui resolver dividindo o width de cada elemento inline e aplicando `inline-block` para os mesmos. Lembrando que, nunca deixe chegar em 100% senão ele vai automaticamente quebrar de linha. `!important` é necessário pois ele sobrepõe o estilo do Bootstrap.

Lembrando que o botão está responsivo ou seja, ele fica grande conforme você vai diminuindo ou aumentando a tela.

```css
.form-group label{
  width:15% !important;
  display:inline-block;
}

.form-group select{
  width:25% !important;
  display:inline-block;
}

.form-group input[type="text"]{
  width:35% !important;
  display:inline-block;
}

.form-group button[type="submit"]{
  width:20% !important;
  display:inline-block;
}

.form-group{

width:100%;

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="row">
<div class="col-lg-12">
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">Pesquisar</div>
    <div class="panel-body">
      <form class="form-inline ">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="sel1">Select list:</label>
            <select class="form-control" id="sel1">
              <option>1</option>
              <option>2</option>
              <option>3</option>
              <option>4</option>
            </select>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="campoPesquisa">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" >Pesquisar</button>
          </div>
      </form>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Ops observei que em "pagina toda" ele não redimensiona, mas testa no seu código isso que eu fiz, talvez funcione pois aqui eu usei o snippet.

Comment: Agora sim o `form-group` não estava em 100%

Comment: Cara, valeu, deu mais ou menos certo. Porem a página é gigante e arrumou essa parte e bagunçou o resto da pagina..kkkk.

Comment: Cara, faz assim remove o "col-md-12 col-xs-12" e poe o "col-lg-12" como você tinha deixado, eu fui remover para ver se era isso !

Comment: @Robss70 Pronto, corrigi vê se isso resolve !

Comment: A parte da pesquisa deu certo, só falta alguns ajustes meus. Porem o resto da pagina saiu de formatação. Acho que é por causa das classes form-group.

Comment: Pode ser também !

Comment: É que a classe form-group ela não está abrangendo todo o formulario, ai acaba ficando só na metade. Vou tentar resolver sem usar o form-group(width:100%)

Comment: Putz, valeu mesmo cara, já não sei mais o que fazer.

Comment: Eu enfrento bastante problemas com o bootstrap por ser algo "pré-moldado" as vezes é difícil personalizar, mas estamos ai, assim que eu resolver já mando para você.